# monetb: what does bind function does with access argument?

Tags: bind, monetdb, monetdb-assembly-language

I am looking into the MAL code of an execution plan for a query. Can anyone explain what the `bind` function does in detail?

Specifically, what does the following MAL statements actually do?

```
X_6:bat[:oid,:int]  := sql.bind(X_2,"sys","region","r_regionkey",0);
(X_9,r1_9) := sql.bind(X_2,"sys","region","r_regionkey",2);
X_12:bat[:oid,:int]  := sql.bind(X_2,"sys","region","r_regionkey",1);
```

My DB has a table region with `r_regionkey` as an attribute. The query I used was:

```
select * from region;
```

Answer (score 0):

MonetDB supports optimistic concurrency control, keeping the deltas around until a convenient moment arises to merge them into the tables.

Comment: ... and the three `bind`s correspond to the original table and the delta's of deletions and additions.